# Get skin path in Magento?

Tags: templates, magento

I have a few custom PHP functions for my Magento store that I stored in myfunc.php and I need to require it from in a few different .phtml files. How do I do that?

I mean I can use an absolute path but that would be dirty and probably problematic when migrating to another server.

For now I'm stuck with:

```
require('/home/myuser/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/myfunc.php');
```

How do I refer to the skin path ( /home/myuser/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/ ) programmatically?

Comment: Please do not put PHP function code to the theme. This should be in the module (`app/code/X/...`)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The way that Magento themes handle actual url's is as such (in view partials - phtml files):

`echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/logo.png');`

If you need the actual base path on disk to the image directory use:

`echo Mage::getBaseDir('skin');`

Some more base directory types are available in this great blog post:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories

Answer (score 17):

First note that

```
Mage::getBaseDir('skin')
```

returns **only** path to skin directory of your Magento install (*/your/magento/dir/skin*).

You can access absolute path to currently used skin directory using:

```
Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseDir()
```

This method accepts an associative array as optional parameter to modify result.

Following keys are recognized:

- **_area** *frontend* (default) or *adminhtml*
- **_package** your package
- **_theme** your theme
- **_relative** when this is set (as an key) path relative to Mage::getBaseDir('skin') is returned.

So in your case correct answer would be:

```
require(Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseDir().DS.'myfunc.php');
```

Answer (score 13):

**To use it in phtml apply :**

```
echo $this->getSkinUrl('your_image_folder_under_skin/image_name.png');
```

**To use skin path in cms page :**

```
<img style="width: 715px; height: 266px;" src="{{skin url=images/banner1.jpg}}" alt="title" />
```

This part====>
    {{skin url=images/banner1.jpg}}

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: What does it adds to the currently accepted answer? This is exactly the same suggested there. This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

To get **current skin** URL use this `Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl()`

Comment: You can pass the path as a parameter `Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('image/example.png')`

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not recommended to have php files with functions in design folder.
You should create a new module or extend (copy from core to local a helper and add function onto that class) and do not change files from app/code/core.

To answer to your question you can use:

```
require(Mage::getBaseDir('design').'/frontend/default/mytheme/myfunc.php');
```

Best practice (as a start) will be to create in /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Helper/Extra.php a php file:

```
<?php
class Mage_Core_Helper_Extra extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

    public function getSomething()
    {
        return 'Someting';
    }

}
```

And to use it in phtml files use:

```
$this->helper('core/extra')->getSomething();
```

Or in all the places:

```
Mage::helper('core/extra')->getSomething();
```

Answer (score -1):

To get that file use the below code.

```
include(Mage::getBaseDir('skin').'myfunc.php');
```

But it is not a correct way. To add your custom functions you can use the below file.

```
app/code/core/Mage/core/functions.php
```

Kindly avoid to use the PHP function under skin dir.

Comment: Any modifications made in app/code/core will be overwritten upon Magento upgrade, and it is therefore inadvisable to make any changes within that hierarchy.