# How to get Magento theme directory?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

First, I was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360096/get-skin-path-in-magento) but that doesn't help because

```
$this->getSkinUrl()
```

Is not what I want since it returns **URL** not **path**

```
Mage::getBaseDir('skin');
```

returns the skin base dir, they may be many themes there..

I want to determine the current theme base dir.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getSkinBaseDir()
```

Answer (score -1):

There may be many themes, but it will be using whatever you have configured and it will go all the way to the package/theme that might have been used in System > Config > Design

If you are looking for dir,

Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getSkinBaseDir()

```
public function getSkinBaseDir(array $params=array())
{
    $params['_type'] = 'skin';
    $this->updateParamDefaults($params);
    $baseDir = (empty($params['_relative']) ? Mage::getBaseDir('skin').DS : '').
        $params['_area'].DS.$params['_package'].DS.$params['_theme'];
    return $baseDir;
}

public function updateParamDefaults(array &$params)
{
    if ($this->getStore()) {
        $params['_store'] = $this->getStore();
    }
    if (empty($params['_area'])) {
        $params['_area'] = $this->getArea();
    }
    if (empty($params['_package'])) {
        $params['_package'] = $this->getPackageName();
    }
    if (empty($params['_theme'])) {
        $params['_theme'] = $this->getTheme( (isset($params['_type'])) ? $params['_type'] : '' );
    }
    if (empty($params['_default'])) {
        $params['_default'] = false;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Here is how you can get the current them path

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].parse_url($this->getSkinUrl(''),PHP_URL_PATH);
```

More details about [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: @sonia - i'm not sure why this answer has been accepted.  I would try and avoid code like this where possible from within a framework such as Magento

Comment: Agreed.  This is a very poor inside Magento as it would completely destroy the theme fallback.  As you are only supposed to to move editted files into your package/theme, and let the system fallback into base/default for everything else.